# Sumar Valores de columnas DataGridView VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, vb

estoy realizando una app y quiero sumar los valores de la columna **SUBTOTAL** clasificándolo por marca (columna **MARCA**), el problema radica en que va a ir variando las marcas. En primera instancia solo ocupaba dos marcas y resolvía el problema con este código...

```
Sub Sumar()
    Dim totalA As Double = 0
    Dim totalB As Double = 0
    For Each fila As DataGridViewRow In dgvDatos.Rows
        If fila.Cells("SUBTOTAL").Value Is Nothing Then
            Exit Sub
        ElseIf fila.Cells("MARCA").Value = "A" Then
            totalA += Convert.ToDouble(fila.Cells("SUBTOTAL").Value)
        ElseIf fila.Cells("MARCA").Value = "B" Then
            totalB += Convert.ToDouble(fila.Cells("SUBTOTAL").Value)
        End If
    Next
    lblA.Text = Format(totalA, "$ #,##0.000")
    lblB.Text = Format(totalB, "$ #,##0.000")
End Sub
```

Pero ahora las marcas pueden ser variables y así como lo estoy manejando tendría que declarar N variables para almacenar el resultado por marca. Alguna sugerencia para optimizar mi operación?
Gracias anticipadas!!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar el algoritmo conocido como [corte de control](http://lsecotaro.blogspot.com.ar/2011/09/corte-de-control.html). En éste enlace que te dejé lo definen de manera sencilla:

"El corte de control es un proceso en el cual partiendo de registros ordenados por el valor de uno o más campos, (denominados campos clave o llave o criterio de ordenamiento) se los procesa en categorías determinadas por los criterios de ordenamiento.
En otras palabras, se procesa un conjunto ordenado de registros en subconjuntos determinados por los criterios de orden."

En tu caso, primero deberías ordenar la tabla dgvDatos por MARCA, para así utilizar este atributo como clasificador. Te adjunto cómo podrías comenzar a modificar tu código (no conozco mucho vb, así que no tomes este ejemplo como solución):

```
Sub Sumar()
    Dim marca as String // Defines la marca para la cual estás sumando sus valores SUBTOTAL.
    Dim totalMarca as Double = 0 // El SUBTOTAL de una marca.

    marca = //Obtener la primera MARCA (en el caso de tu ejemplo cuando este ordenado sería 'A')

    For Each fila As DataGridViewRow In dgvDatos.Rows
     If fila.Cells("SUBTOTAL").Value Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
     if(marca = fila.Cells("MARCA").Value) then
        totalMarca += Convert.ToDouble(fila.Cells("SUBTOTAL").Value)
     else
        lblMARCA.Text = Format(totalMarca, "$ #,##0.000")
        marca = fila.Cells("MARCA").Value
    End if

    Next
End Sub
```

De ésta manera, ordenando tu tabla como primer paso, te quedarían todas las filas pertenecientes a la MARCA 'A', luego todas las filas de la siguiente MARCA y así. El algoritmo suma todos los SUBTOTALES perteneciente a la primera marca, hasta encontrar una diferente a ésta y ahí setea la variable marca con la nueva marca (la siguiente a la primera definida que es 'A') para comenzar con todo el proceso de nuevo.

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza un diccionario, no requiere tener los datos  ordenados.

En el código donde haces la suma:

```
Sub Sumar()
    Dim dict as new Dictionary(Of String, Double)

    For Each fila In dgvDatos.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)
        If fila.Cells("SUBTOTAL").Value IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim marca = fila.Cells("MARCA").Value.ToString()
            Dim subtotal = Convert.ToDouble(fila.Cells("SUBTOTAL").Value)          
            Dim currentValue = If(dict.ContainsKey(marca), dict.Item(marca), 0.0R)
            If dict.ContainsKey(marca) then
                dict.Item(marca) = currentValue  + subtotal
            else
                dict.Add(marca, currentValue  + subtotal)
            EndIf
        End If
    Next
    lblMarcas.Text = String.Empty
    For Each marca in dict
        lblMarcas.Text += "Subtotal de " & marca.Key & " = " & Format(marca.Value, "$ #,##0.000") & Environment.NewLine
    Next
 End Sub
```

Lo hago de memoria, no tengo visual studio a la mano para probar

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes tu Datagridview asociado a un DataTable (dgvDatos.DataSource = TablaDgvDatos) puedes usar el método Compute del DataTable.

```
Sub Sumar()
    lblA.Text = Format(TablaDgvDatos.Compute("SUM(SUBTOTAL)", "MARCA = 'A'"), "$ #,##0.000")
    lblB.Text = Format(TablaDgvDatos.Compute("SUM(SUBTOTAL)", "MARCA = 'B'"), "$ #,##0.000")
    lblAV.Text = Format(TablaDgvDatos.Compute("SUM(SUBTOTAL)", "MARCA = 'AV'"), "$ #,##0.000")
End Sub
```

Si estas marcas van a ser variables en el tiempo y te refieres a no tener que modificar tu código cuando haya una nueva marca por ejemplo, especifica cómo lees las marcas que quieres sumar para poder sugerirte una solución.

Answer (score 0):

Si el juego de datos está en la base de datos, tienes el siguiente comando `SELECT` que te estaría dando lo que buscas:

```
SELECT MARCA, sum(importe) as TotalMarca
FROM "tutabla"
GROUP BY MARCA
ORDER BY MARCA
```

La mejor forma de mostrar este resultado es otra grilla, pero tiene la ventaja que no importa la cantidad de Marcas que tengas funcionará.

Puede crearte un stored procedure  o bien puedes lanzar la ejecución de la consulta contra la base de datos.